# Extension of smooth Weyl invariant function

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $T$ a maximal torus. Let $f$ be a smooth ($\mathbb{R}$-valued) function on $T$ which is Weyl-invariant, that is, $f(w \cdot t) = f(t)$ for all $w \in W$ the Weyl group. Then I want to show there is a smooth class function $F$ on $G$ such that $F$ restricted to $T$ gives $f$. If you require only continuity (rather than smoothness) it is fairly easy to prove.

Clearly you want to define $F(gtg^{-1}) = f(t)$. The obstacle, it seems to me, is that the map $(g,t) \mapsto gtg^{-1}$ is smooth and but its derivative vanishes at singular points. At the regular points, you can use the inverse function theorem to give you a local diffeomorphism from an open subset of $G \times T$ to $G$, so you have a smooth local inverse. Thus $F$ will be smooth on the set of regular points, but I don't see how to show it is smooth for all points. Is there a way around this?